# nginx - how can I serve Wordpress from my domain's root but also serve static content from other directories?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm just getting started with administering my own VPS at Digital Ocean and playing with nginx configs for multi-domain sites.

This is what I want to achieve:

- `foo.com/` maps to `/usr/share/nginx/www/wordpress`
- `foo.com/bar` maps to `/usr/share/nginx/www/bar` (if it exists, otherwise try this URL with Wordpress above)
- `foo.com/baz.jpg` maps to `/usr/share/nginx/www/baz.jpg`

Essentially, I want the `www` directory to just be a static location but also to be able to serve Wordpress from a subfolder (so I don't have to mix all my other files in with Wordpress's folder structure).

Does this make sense, and is it possible?

Here's my nginx config so far:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     foo.com;
    root        /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;

    location @wp {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www/foo;
        # index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @wp;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

}
```

Apologies if this sounds stupid, I'm still getting my head around how nginx works and what's possible with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close, but you need some tweaks, I removed some stuff and modified other

```
location @wp {
    rewrite ^ /wordpress/index.php?q=$1;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wp;
}
# add php location
```